# in Valid Anagram program not passing all test cases

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, data-structures

Given two strings s and t , write a function to determine if t is an anagram of s.

Example 1:

Input: s = "anagram", t = "nagaram"
Output: true
Example 2:

Input: s = "rat", t = "car"
Output: false

example 3
"aad"
"cab"
Output
true
Expected
false

my 3 test case is giving output true why?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        if (s.isEmpty() && t.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (s.length() != t.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        char[] a = s.toCharArray();
        char[] b = t.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(a);
        Arrays.sort(b);
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= b.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                    return true;    
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You iterate each time over the second list per item in the first list. Furthermore you increment the `i` and `j` twice.

Comment: if i do single then also 3rd one showing true

Comment: because, as said before, you icrement twice.

Comment: and then why does 1st  example working but not 3rd one

Comment: well you made three mistakes, so it is not unlikely that sometimes, "by accident", it will work. After all, there are only two possible results: `true` and `false`, so a random response might have some correct results as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a nested for loop, you will iterate over every possible pair *(i, j)* with *i* and *j* an in idex in `a` and `b` respectively. Furthermore you use `i++` and `j++` twice, and thus you will skip the even indices. You can not return `true` from the moment `a[i++] == b[j++]` matches. In order to know if something is an anagram, you need to iterate over all elements. You can return `false` from the moment `a[i] != b[i]` however. Finally the bound should be `i < a.length`, not `i <= a.length`.

You thus need one `for` loop where you make a single increment and compare `a[i]` with `b[i]`:

```
public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
    if(s.length() != t.length()){
        return false;
    }
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    char[] b = t.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] != b[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: array index out of bounds

Comment: @NaveenVerma: of course, since the condition should be `i < a.length`, not `i <= a.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just comparing the first letter of **cab** and **rat** which is **a**, and returning True, actually you need to check all letters.

Hence make the condition negative and swap the returns.

```
 if(a[i++] !=b[j++]){
   return false;
  } 
return true;
```

The above code will return false, when characters aren’t equal, hence the last line is reached only when all chars are equal.